# Could not Uninstall a Package

Tags: uninstall

I am using Ubuntu14.04. I downloaded a "ISO Master" software as a "iso-master-1-3-8-es-en-br-fr-de-it-cn-ar-ru-ubu.deb" file and i installed it via terminal. Now, my problem is i am unable to remove this package.I tried to remove this package via both Ubuntu Software Center and Synaptic package manager.Both of these didn't show me the option "remove". It shows only a "Install" option.But,ISO master is already installed in my system and it also available in dash board.Then, why i can't see a remove option.Then i also tried to remove it via terminal. It shows me a following errors.

Running sudo apt-get remove isomaster
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package 'isomaster' is not installed, so not removed. Did you mean 'isomaster:i386'?
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra libatk-bridge2.0-0:i386 libatspi2.0-0:i386
  libcairo-gobject2:i386 libcolord1:i386 libdbusmenu-gtk3-4:i386
  libgtk-3-0:i386 libnss3-1d:i386 libphonon4 libwayland-client0:i386
  libwayland-cursor0:i386 libxkbcommon0:i386 linux-headers-generic
  linux-image-generic phonon phonon-backend-gstreamer
  phonon-backend-gstreamer-common phonon-backend-gstreamer1.0
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up hspa-modem-dkms (1.02.35) ...
Removing old hspa-modem-1.02.35 DKMS files...

---

Deleting module version: 1.02.35

### completely from the DKMS tree.

Done.
Loading new hspa-modem-1.02.35 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.13.0-34-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.13.0-34-generic
Error!  The dkms.conf for this module includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which
does not match this kernel/arch.  This indicates that it should not be built.
Skipped.
Removing old hspa-modem-1.02.35 DKMS files...

---

Deleting module version: 1.02.35

### completely from the DKMS tree.

Done.
Loading new hspa-modem-1.02.35 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.13.0-34-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.13.0-34-generic
Error!  The dkms.conf for this module includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which
does not match this kernel/arch.  This indicates that it should not be built.
dpkg: error processing package hspa-modem-dkms (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 9
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Running sudo apt-get remove ISO Master
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ISO
E: Unable to locate package Master

please can anyone tell me what is the problem and how to remove that software from my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo dpkg -r isomaster:i386
```

Check in the Ubuntu Software Center to make sure that the exact spelling of the package's name is *isomaster:i386*.